# Sieve of Eratosthenes C++ code

Tags: c++, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm fairly new to programming, and I just started C++

I found this problem, which involved generation all prime numbers upto "n". This is my code, where I've assumed "n" to be 10. I've tried my best. I'd really appreciate it if you guys could tell me what's wrong.

The for loop that's in a separate blockquote is repeating indefinitely, that means the value of i isn't being updated. I used a cout statement to print the value, it's either 0 or 1. Why is this happening? Is there a fault in the logic?

> ```
> #include<iostream> 
> #include<cstdlib>
>
> using namespace std;
>
> int main()
> {
>     int NumList[10], flag[10];
>     int i,j;
>
>
>     for(i = 0; i<10; i++) //Generate a list of numbers from 1 to 10
>         NumList[i] = i+1;
>
>
>
>     for(i = 0; i<10; i++) // Create a flag array, initialized to 1
>         flag[i] = 1;
>
>     for(i=1; i<10; i++)
>     {
>      if(NumList[i]%2==0)  // Mark all even numbers in the list
>         flag[i] = 0;      // since they're not prime
>     }
> ```

```
    for(i = 2; i<10; i++)        //Start from 3
{
        if(flag[i]==1)      // Check which numbers are left over
    {
        for(j = NumList[i]-1;j<10; ) //Since index = value-1 in this case
        {
            j+= NumList[i];     //Keep incrementing by value and marking in flag[]
            flag[j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: First and foremost your code looks like it's going to eliminate 2 as not prime.

Comment: I know that. I'll just add a 2 during output. It seems simpler to do that.

Comment: Why don't *you* tell us what's wrong, and maybe then we can explain why that's wrong.

Comment: I checked it out. It's going into an infinite loop. I don't know why.

Comment: When you remove the `flag[j] = 0;` line, it doesn't go into an infinite loop. It looks like that line is somehow messing with the value of `i`, and i am at a loss to explain that.

Comment: Do you see any fault in the logic?

Comment: What's the value of `NumList[i]` in that inner loop, hmm?

Comment: Either 3 or 1, for some reason.

Comment: When I run this code it seg-faults. That happens because you are accessing out of bounds when after repeated incrementing of j by whatever lives in NumList[i] (the numbers 3 to 10 if letting i start at 2) you then try to use this ever-inflating value as an index to an array that should only have 10 elements - namely flag[j] = 0

Comment: `flag[j] = 0;` --> `if(j<10) flag[j] = 0;`

Comment: Shouldn't the condition j<10 in the for loop stop it from going out of bounds?

Comment: no ... since you access out of bounds before the current loop iteration finishes. I.e you access out of bounds, and **then** check whether j < 10, by which point it is too late.

Answer (score 1):

The code is looping infinitely because you have accessed out of bounds in the following loop

```
for(j = NumList[i] - 1; j<10; )
{
    j += NumList[i];
    flag[j] = 0;
}
```

given that Numlist[i] is 3 when i = 2 in your outer loop, and j starts of as 2 in your inner loop, the following happens:

```
j takes value 2+3, flag[5] is assigned the value 0, current loop ends check 5 < 10
j takes value 5+3, flag[8] is assigned the value 0, current loop ends check 8 < 10
j takes value 8+3, flag[11] is assigned the value 0, current loop ends check 11 < 10
```

Once the third loop has finished (having modified flag[11]) all bets are off with respect to what will happen next. Indeed it is plausible that you are clobbering some other variable you have defined which is living at the address referenced by flag[11].

As for making this problem going away, with least disturbance to your current logic (whatever it is - it doesn't look correct) you can just increase the size of the flags array.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Though, the logic is correct. I'm getting the desired output.